# Custom drop down z-index issue with input placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

Hi I have create custom filtering drop down for country list display on angular project. i have design input as two columns. Under country drop down there is another input field as phone no. My issue is when i type on county input the data successfully filter and display under , But phone no input placeholder still can see and editable. i want to drop down display as top of all other elements.

[image]

[image]

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6 z-10">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label ng-show="policyHolder.nationality" class="show-hide">Nationality</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control ktz-text-input-trp"
            placeholder="Nationality" name="Nationality"
            ng-model="policyHolder.nationality" ng-blur="HideDropList_Nationality()"
            autocomplete="off"
            ng-change="searchNationality(policyHolder.nationality)" required>
            <div id="nationalityDropDown">
                <ul class="list-group" ng-if="ShowNationalityDropDown == true">
                    <li class="list-group-item dropDown_nationality"
                        ng-repeat='Nationality in nationalityListSearchResults track by $index'
                        >
                        <div ng-click="selectedNationality(Nationality)">
                            {{Nationality.content}} ({{Nationality['@code']}})
                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <span class="ktz-text-error"
            ng-show="policyHolderForm.Nationality.$error.required && isSumbit">Nationality can not be empty !</span>
            <span class="ktz-text-error"
            ng-show="invalidNationality == true">Invalid Nationality!</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 z-10">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label ng-show="policyHolder.phone" class="show-hide">Phone</label>
            <input phone-mask type="text" phone-number
            ng-class="{ ktzformerror: (policyHolderForm.phone.$error.required && isSumbit) }"
            class="form-control ktz-text-input-trp" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"
            ng-model="policyHolder.phone" ng-blur="updateFirstTraveller()">
            <!--<span class="ktz-text-error" ng-show="policyHolderForm.phone.$error.required && isSumbit">Phone number can not be empty !</span>-->
            <span class="ktz-text-error"
            ng-show="policyHolderForm.phone.$error.phoneNumber && isSumbit">Phone number must be exactly 8 digits !</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    .dropDown_nationality {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: transparent;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    #nationalityDropDown ul li {
        font-size: 14px !important;
        display: block;
        z-index: 600 !important;
    }

    #nationalityDropDown ul {
        min-width: 350px !important;
        max-width: 350px !important;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 600 !important;
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }


$scope.searchNationality = function (data) {
        var output = [];
        if (data != "" && data != undefined) {
            $scope.ShowNationalityDropDown = true;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.nationalityList.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.nationalityList[i].content.toLowerCase().startsWith(data.toLowerCase())) {
                    output.push($scope.nationalityList[i]);
                }
            }
            $scope.nationalityListSearchResults = output;
        } else {
            $scope.ShowNationalityDropDown = false;
            $scope.nationalityListSearchResults = [];
        }
    };

$scope.selectedNationality = function (selected) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.policyHolder.nationality = selected.content;
            $scope.policyHolder.nationality_code = selected['@code'];
        });

    };
```

Comment: kindly add JS code as well

Comment: hi i have update the code

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

```js
angular.module('ddApp', [])
    .controller('ddAppController', function($scope, $timeout){

$scope.nationalityList = [{ content:"countryA", visibility:false }
,{ content:"countryB", visibility:false }
,{ content:"countryC", visibility:false }
,{ content:"countryD", visibility:false }
,{ content:"countryE", visibility:false }
,{ content:"countryF", visibility:false }
,{ content:"countryG", visibility:false }
 ];

        
        $scope.searchNationality = function (data) {
            var output = [];
            if (data != "" && data != undefined) {
                $scope.ShowNationalityDropDown = true;
                
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.nationalityList.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.nationalityList[i].content.toLowerCase().startsWith(data.toLowerCase())) {
                        output.push($scope.nationalityList[i]);
                    }
                }
                $scope.nationalityListSearchResults = output;
            } else {
                $scope.ShowNationalityDropDown = false;
                $scope.nationalityListSearchResults = [];
            }
        };
        
        $scope.selectedNationality = function (selected) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.policyHolder.nationality = selected.content;
                $scope.policyHolder.nationality_code = selected['@code'];
                $scope.ShowNationalityDropDown = false;
            });
            
        };
    });
```

```css
.dropDown_nationality {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: transparent;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    #nationalityDropDown ul li {
        font-size: 14px !important;
        display: block;
        z-index: 600 !important;
    }

    #nationalityDropDown ul {
        min-width: 350px !important;
        max-width: 350px !important;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 600 !important;
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding-left:0;
        margin-top:0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = 'ddApp'>
        <div ng-controller= 'ddAppController'>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 z-10">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label ng-show="policyHolder.nationality" class="show-hide">Nationality</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ktz-text-input-trp"
                    placeholder="Nationality" name="Nationality"
                    ng-model="policyHolder.nationality" ng-blur="HideDropList_Nationality()"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    ng-change="searchNationality(policyHolder.nationality)" required>
                    <div id="nationalityDropDown">
                        <ul class="list-group" ng-if="ShowNationalityDropDown == true">
                            <li class="list-group-item dropDown_nationality"
                                ng-repeat='Nationality in nationalityListSearchResults track by $index'
                                >
                                <div ng-click="selectedNationality(Nationality)">
                                    {{Nationality.content}} ({{Nationality['@code']}})
                                </div>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="ktz-text-error"
                    ng-show="policyHolderForm.Nationality.$error.required && isSumbit">Nationality can not be empty !</span>
                    <span class="ktz-text-error"
                    ng-show="invalidNationality == true">Invalid Nationality!</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 z-10">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label ng-show="policyHolder.phone" class="show-hide">Phone</label>
                    <input phone-mask type="text" phone-number
                    ng-class="{ ktzformerror: (policyHolderForm.phone.$error.required && isSumbit) }"
                    class="form-control ktz-text-input-trp" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"
                    ng-model="policyHolder.phone" ng-blur="updateFirstTraveller()">
                    <!--<span class="ktz-text-error" ng-show="policyHolderForm.phone.$error.required && isSumbit">Phone number can not be empty !</span>-->
                    <span class="ktz-text-error"
                    ng-show="policyHolderForm.phone.$error.phoneNumber && isSumbit">Phone number must be exactly 8 digits !</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes it works, the problem is not in the data filtering its about css. Can u please check the images i attached here.

Comment: what do you mean? if you "Run code snippet" in my answer, you'll see that the css now pushes the phone number field down and the user can select an country they want... do you want the country dropDown to be on top of the Phone number field? ensuring that the phone number field is covered completely and not editable??

Comment: Hi i did, thank you. Can u check my images. i need drop down covered phone no field totally. I did this as your code before but my client complain me to there shouldn't be any shake when drop down activating (going pone no field up and down). hope you got my idea

Comment: hi @MaheshSanjeewa, unable to get to it earlier... kindly check